# Nested generalizations of exponential and logarithmic integral functions

Tags: integration, reference-request, special-functions

For $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) is defined as follows: $$\operatorname{Ei}(x) := PV \int_{-\infty}^{x}  \frac{e^{t}}{t}dt. $$ Here, $PV(\cdot)$ is the Cauchy principal value.

Several generalizations of this special functions have been considered, including the ones associated with the $E_{n}(\cdot)$ [function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) and [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kwara-Nantomah/publication/315714765_A_Generalization_of_the_Exponential_Integral_and_Some_Associated_Inequalities/links/58de2e2092851cd2d3e4bbef/A-Generalization-of-the-Exponential-Integral-and-Some-Associated-Inequalities.pdf?origin=publication_detail) by Nantomah et al.

I wonder whether the following, nested generlization of the exponential integral has been considered already in the literature. Let $\operatorname{Ei}(1,x) := \operatorname{Ei}(x),   $ and define $$\operatorname{Ei}(2,y) := PV \int_{-\infty}^{y} \frac{\operatorname{Ei}(1,x)}{x} dx. $$

We further define every nested exponential integral of subsequent order by the recursive relationship $$\operatorname{Ei}(m,z) := PV \int_{-\infty}^{z} \frac{\operatorname{Ei}(m-1,x)}{x} dx , \tag{*}$$ somewhat like the polylogarithms.

Altough I have found a few double integrals of the exponential integral function before (see for instance p. 618 of [volume 1](https://vdoc.pub/documents/integrals-and-series-vol-1-elem-functions-6fdspu20qer0) of Integrals and Series by Prudnikov et al.), I haven't encountered this generalization of the exponential integral before. I wonder what its properties are, and if definite integrals over it can could be obtained. One could do something similar for the logarithmic integral function.

> **Question**: have the nested exponential integral functions as defined in $(*)$ been described in the literature before?

Comment: You can find the (delay?) differential equation $\frac {dy(m,z)}{dz}=\frac{y(m-1,z)}z$ and use initial values to define the function. Ei$(2,z)$ is partly shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%28integral+Ei%28x%29%2Fx+%29%2Fx). The function might have the form $\,_m \text F _m (1,…,1;2,…,2;x)+f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a rational function of $\ln$, the euler mascheroni constant, $\pi$, and $x$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Nice, thanks. $f(x)$ also appears to include the incomplete Gamma function

Comment: @TymaGaidash Ah I see, indeed. Would be cool if the hypergeometric function has some closed forms for certain values of $x$